# account transaction procedure in database?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-normalization

i am creating db design for supermarket so now i need to normalize account transaction in customer and dealer .

I like to know about the transaction procedure in super market or Departmental stores for My database design.

If anyone know about whats the link between customer and dealer in a supermarket.
Let me know.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your question. But I think this is what you need to read.

http://www.versant.com/products/fast-objects

Just learn some basic stuff. This may be helpful